# IIS URL Rewrite and Web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I don't understand anything about IIS, but am trying to solve this problem of redirecting all visitors to `example.com/page` to `example.com/page.html`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
          <rewriteMaps>
              <rewriteMap name="StaticRedirects">
                  <add key="/page" value="/page.html" />
              </rewriteMap>
            </rewriteMaps>
      </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

A couple of problems arise:

1. I don't know where to even put the file. There is a User root directory, and an htdocs directory, I tried both, no joy.
2. I don't even know if the account can do rewrites, I am trying to find that out.

Comment: Always, though I can't use it now...but for the future, or maybe to help others :)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

1) Your existing web.config: you have declared rewrite map .. but have not created any rules that will use it. RewriteMap on its' own does absolutely nothing.

2) Below is how you can do it (it does not utilise rewrite maps -- rules only, which is fine for small amount of rewrites/redirects):

This rule will do SINGLE EXACT rewrite (internal redirect) `/page` to `/page.html`. URL in browser will remain unchanged.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="SpecificRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^page$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/page.html" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

This rule #2 will do the same as above, but will do 301 redirect (Permanent Redirect) where URL will change in browser.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="SpecificRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^page$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/page.html" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Rule #3 will attempt to execute such rewrite for ANY URL if there are such file with .html extension (i.e. for `/page` it will check if `/page.html` exists, and if it does then rewrite occurs):

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="DynamicRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html" matchType="IsFile" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.html" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Was trying to understand these maps and your answer helped alot. Thanks. My +1

Comment: @CodeSherpa I believe Tomek gave correct solution a bit: just alter yours: add `<conditions><add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" /></conditions>` and maybe use `^register\.aspx$` (notice the \ character -- this will ensure that only `register.aspx` will be redirected, and not `register2aspx` etc.). Also -- make sure that **URL Rewrite Module** is installed (it is separate download = not bundled with IIS by default).

Comment: @LazyOne can u help me out for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904849/url-mapping-works-on-localhost-but-not-on-production-server-in-asp-net

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE That's different: It's URL Rewriting module here while yours is actual .NET config (which works a bit differently, AFAIK, and has nuances, which I'm not familiar with).

Comment: do u have any complete sample example for above so that i should try? i am new to the url rewritting module so...!

Comment: i am trying url rewritting with Query string but no get success plz help me  ` <asp:HyperLink ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Client" CssClass="button1 black"
                            NavigateUrl="EditClient.aspx/0"></asp:HyperLink>` and web config rul is  ` <rewrite>
     <rules>
     
        <rule name="Rewrite Articles">
       <match url="^EditClient.aspx/([0-9])" />
       <action type="Rewrite" url="EditClient.aspx?ID={R:1}" />
      </rule>
     
     </rules>
    </rewrite>`   how to show url linke EditClient.aspx/0 or something numeric id   plz help me my Ac block so ask Que

Comment: If for some reason you like me need to have a NOT condition, just use the attribute `negate="true"` :)

Answer (score 18):

Just wanted to point out one thing missing in LazyOne's answer (I would have just commented under the answer but don't have enough rep)

In rule #2 for permanent redirect there is thing missing:

`redirectType="Permanent"`

So rule #2 should look like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="SpecificRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^page$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/page.html" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

**Edit**

For more information on how to use the URL Rewrite Module see this excellent documentation: [URL Rewrite Module Configuration Reference](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference)

In response to @kneidels question from the comments; To match the url: `topic.php?id=39` something like the following could be used:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="SpecificRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^topic.php$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(?:id)=(\d{2})" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="/newpage/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

This will match `topic.php?id=ab` where `a` is any number between `0-9` and b is also any number between `0-9`.
It will then redirect to `/newpage/xy` where `xy` comes from the original url.
I have not tested this but it should work.

Comment: Hey. This solution works great for statis files. How would it look with a match url of: `match url="topic.php?id=39"` ?

Comment: @kneidels: I just updated the answer, see if that helps

Comment: +1 for providing the link to the iis.net documentation ( which I see is redirected now to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference )

Comment: So I managed to get this to work but for some reason it only work if have the directory ~ i.e. /pages - why is this directory needed ~ can I just reference it without it needing to exist?

Answer (score 12):

Just tried this rule, and it worked with GoDaddy hosting since they've already have the Microsoft URL Rewriting module installed for every IIS 7 account.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="enquiry" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^enquiry$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/Enquiry.aspx" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thanks to you mentioning the module being installed I realised that I didn't have it installed and managed to overcome my problem :)