# IIS URL rewrite - with dynamic files

Tags: mod-rewrite, iis-7

I am using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13861795/848513 which works great for static files, which no longer exist on my site, to forwards to new file locations.

But I also have some dynamic URL's that need to be forwarded to new locations, and the following code doesn't seem to work:

Works:

```
    <rule name="SpecificRedirect50" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="aboutus.php" />   <!-- static URL -->
      <action type="Redirect" url="/about-us" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Does not work:

```
    <rule name="SpecificRedirect1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="topic.php?id=39" />   <!-- dynamic URL-->
      <action type="Redirect" url="/folder/?id=520" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

The error i get when trying to go to www.site.com/topic.php?id=39 is a 404 Not Found error - ie, it isn't being filtered by the rewrite script.

What should the format be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK, found answer - this format works:

```
    <rule name="SpecificRedirect1111" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^topic\.php$" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^id=39$" />
        </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="/folder/?id=520" appendQueryString="false"  redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```