# Creating a redirect from a different domain on the correct server with web.config

Tags: redirect, web-config

I have created a new site on a new domain – I have no control over the old domain, but the former host has been kind to change the DNS so it points to the correct IP.

As it is set up now, the old URL shows the correct content, but the URI does not change as I want it to. The unusual thing in this case is that the old url is actually a subdomain of a domain that is still in use (but which I have zero control over, so a 301 redirect from there is impractical).

More concretely, http://subdomain.olddomain.com/ reaches the correct IP and shows the correct content, but from there on I want it to redirect to http://newdomain.com/

For now I am content with redirecting all traffic to the root of the new site, but I might do specific page redirects later on.

I've tried variations of this in the web.config:

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Found">
    <add wildcard="^subomain.olddomain.com" destination="http://newdomain.com/" />
</httpRedirect>
```

I was hoping this would work, but unfortunately it does nothing. If I change the wildcard to something like `*default.htm`, it does redirect, so I imagine it's not completely wrong.

I would prefer to avoid messing with IIS etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find a way around this? I'm trying to redirect between domains using wildcards only also.

Comment: @Organic Hi! I put it on the shelf for a while, but I will give it another shot ASAP. The technical support team for my hosting gave up on it, but I'm sure there must be a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make this in Global.asax and if that is not enough you need to perform a frame redirect in the DNS for the domain. However, if it is enough you can do it using Global.asax like this:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (!Context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            string url = Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("://mydomain.", "://mydomain.");
            url = url.Replace("http:", "https:");
            Response.Redirect(url, true); //True causes the current request to abort and force a instant redirect.
        }
        else
        {
            if (Context.Request.Url.ToString().StartsWith("https://mydomain."))
            {
                string url = Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("https://mydomain.", "https://www.mydomain.");
                Response.Redirect(url, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is only a simple example to redirect from http to https (secure) protocol, but can easily be used to redirect to other locations etc. Remember if it still says the old url you need a frame redirect. But according to documentation Response.Redirect occurs in the browser.

As a last resort you can do a ugly approach (just to make it behave as you like):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Dummy</title><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.yoururlhere.com/" /></head><body></body></html>
```

The last example shows how you should return html to the browser in Application_BeginRequest if url is faulty and it will execute on the client side. Or as a standalone index.htm file will also work.

If if you do it in IIS later:
[Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution really is IIS Rewrite, but it's not to be feared. You don't have to use the IIS UI at all, it's all in the web.config. Might take a little time to get your syntax right, but it will be worth it.

Look at Rule 2 from this post:
[IIS URL Rewrite and Web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410067/iis-url-rewrite-and-web-config)