# Remove certain part of URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website where i have pages like:

```
domain.com/?p=settings

domain.com/?p=daily
```

And i am looking for rewrite that `?p=` part, so it would be like

```
domain.com/settings
```

So far i have tried to add this to htaccess files:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1?p= [NC,L]
```

but it did not worked.

Also I have tried look from Google but could not find any.

I have tried other RewriteRule's but they did not work either.

Comment: You can rewrite your url from IIS level. refer this link, may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410067/iis-url-rewrite-and-web-config

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule does not include query string. It is available as a separate variable [enter link description here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

> The Pattern will initially be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string (e.g. "/app1/index.html"). This is the (%-decoded) URL-path.

So the following won't work.

> `RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1?p= [NC,L]`

You need something like

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^/ %2?
```

Checkout [Apache Mod ReWrite Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString) and scroll down to "Making the Query String Part of the Path"

Answer (score 0):

You were close with your attempt, you need to use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?p=$1 [L]
```

Make sure to clear your cache before testing this.