# Classic ASP Querystring Rewrite using web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, web-config, query-string

plateform : classic ASP

I have thousands of pages like that where filename querstring value changes.

```
www.mydomain.com/files.asp?filename=cisco

www.mydomain.com/files.asp?filename=oracle

www.mydomain.com/files.asp?filename=novell

www.mydomain.com/files.asp?filename=teradata
```

I want to show some friendly urls to online viewers so i think i will have to use web.config rewrite for it.

friendly like below

```
www.mydomain.com/files/cisco

www.mydomain.com/files/oracle

www.mydomain.com/files/novell

www.mydomain.com/files/teradata
```

Please tell me what i can do to achieve it.

Comment: See if this helps you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/user-friendly-url-rule-template

Comment: urlrewite module

Comment: I don't have access to hosting's iis server so it is  not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

using `URL_REWRITE_MODULE` you can add rules to the web.config file on your root directory

example:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>

<rule name="Cisco">
<match url="files/cisco" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="files.asp?filename=cisco" />
</rule>

<!-- add as many rule as you please -->

</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: you did not read my question carefully , i wrote "I have thousands of pages".

Comment: Sorry about that. here you go https://stackoverflow.com/a/6741094/2477599
rule #3 will work for you i guess :)