# How to make IIS application rather than host Web site handle initial request?

Tags: .net, iis

Let's say that I have a website with address [www.MyWebsite.com](http://www.MyWebsite.com). Under that site I have a dotnet cshtml "application" found at [www.MyWebsite.com/MyApplication](http://www.MyWebsite.com/MyApplication). The actual start page of the application is [www.MyWebsite.com/MyApplication/Home/Index](http://www.MyWebsite.com/MyApplication/Home/Index).

When a user simply inputs [www.MyWebsite.com/MyApplication](http://www.MyWebsite.com/MyApplication) that should be interpreted by IIS as [www.MyWebsite.com/MyApplication/Home/Index](http://www.MyWebsite.com/MyApplication/Home/Index). But that doesn't happen, causing the application not to load an image whose path it cannot find.

Suggestions?

Comment: You can use [IIS URL Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410067/iis-url-rewrite-and-web-config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a script to test for '/home/index' in the document.location.href, and if not found, to add that to the document.location.href. Works instantly.

Comment: If you can mark your answer, it will lead more people in the right direction.